# How to Print Unicode (Bangla Font) to Thermal Printer?

Tags: java, android, printing, thermal-printer

I want to Print `Bangla` text Like "আপনি কি ডাটা সংরক্ষন করতে চান" from my android app.But i got wrong result every time. Here is my Output:

[image]

My Code is Here:

```
   String memo = "আপনি কি ডাটা সংরক্ষন করতে চান" + "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\n";

    byte[] buffer = memo.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));


    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        byte[] printformat = {27, 33, 01};
        mmOutputStream.write(printformat);
        mmOutputStream.write(buffer);
        mmOutputStream.write(0x0B);
        mmOutputStream.write(0x0B);
        mmOutputStream.write(0x0B);
        mmOutputStream.flush();

        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Completed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mmOutputStream.close();
        mmSocket.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Excep IntentPrint", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: What is on the other end of the socket?

Comment: Does the printer support UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: yes,printer support UTF-8 encoding. we can print Bangla text from window machine via Bluetooth.

Comment: @Md.ZakirHossain I need your help, Did you find any perfect solution ???

Comment: @ Nazmus Saadat Yes, its depend on your printer. I solved it for epson printer

Answer (score 3):

First of all please check the printer has bangla font support. if not then another way you can print.  you need to capture the layout which has the bangla text as image (bitmap)  then use the printers bitmap printing api.  I had the same problem for arabic text. i solve this problem using this technique.  thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that the printer can handle multi-byte sequences of UTF-8.
At the same time printer specific control bytes are written. I think the printer has only a limited and specific ASCII (8 bit) character set.

So try it out:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[128];
for (int i = 0; i < 128; ++i) {
    buffer[i] = (byte)(-128 + i);
}
```

If you cannot find some documentation, you need to map all by hand.

And then you need to map characters in strings like `"\u098F\u09AC\u0982"` to their byte values.

```
Map<Character, Byte> charsToByte;
charsToByte.put('\u088F', (byte)129); // Or such.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it in your printer's datasheet.

for example, My printer **HOP-E200 58mm Mini Portable Thermal Printer** datasheet says

[image]